# Connecting to embedded FireBird database from C# app issue

Tags: c#, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

I seem to have an issue with connecting to an embedded FireBird database from a sample C# app. Here's what I've got.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //Some constant parameters used to form up the connection string... 
        #region constant literals
        const String User = "SYSDBA";
        const String Password = "masterkey";
        const String DBPath = "D:\\!tmp\\1\\cafw.fdb";
        const String DLLPath = @"fbembed.dll";
        const String Charset = "WIN1251";
        const int Dialect = 3;
        #endregion

        //I check whether we actually have a database file nearby
        //and fbembed.dll. If we don't - we leave
        if (File.Exists(DBPath) == true && File.Exists(DLLPath) == true)
        {
            //I form up a connection string out of literals I've declared above
            FbConnectionStringBuilder CStr = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();

            CStr.ServerType = FbServerType.Embedded;                
            CStr.UserID = User;
            CStr.Password = Password;                
            CStr.Dialect = Dialect;                
            CStr.Database = DBPath;
            CStr.Charset = Charset;                                
            CStr.ClientLibrary = DLLPath;

            //And then I finally try to connect
            FbConnection Conn = new FbConnection(CStr.ToString());                

            try
            {
                //See what we've got in the end
                Console.WriteLine(CStr.ToString());
                //And try to connect
                Conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                //Show me what has gone wrong
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + Ex.Message.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            finally
            {
                Conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, it yields me a

> server type=Embedded;user id=SYSDBA;password=masterkey;dialect=3;initial catalog=D:!tmp\1
>   \cafw.fdb;character set=WIN1251;client library=fbembed.dll
>
> No message for error code 335544972 found.
>
> Invalid ESCAPE sequence

as an output.

I've googled around to find out about 335544972 error code, and it seems to be something about invalid connection string, but I haven't found any "official" info about that.

Hase anybody encountered anything similar so one could tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

UPD:
As it has been adviced, I've tried to simplify my connection string. So, instead of what was done above I used

```
FbConnection Conn = new FbConnection("Database=D:\\tmp\\1\\cafw.fdb;ServerType=1");
```

and it gave me a message that "Trusted Auth isn't supported on Embedded Firebird". So, I tried to use a regular sysdba login

```
FbConnection Conn = new FbConnection("Database=D:\\tmp\\1\\cafw.fdb;ServerType=1;User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey");
```

and got the very same error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weird stuff.

It is hard to believe, but the only reason I can name for this is that my c# solution resided somewhere in d:......\c#\myAppProject (yeah, it's all about # sign).

After I replaced the project, all worked correct.

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't your answer but it was for me, so..

You must make sure you supply a User and Password even though they are not required (any password will do).